# Creating network interface with no IP address on CentOS 7

Tags: routing, linux-networking, centos7, interface

I'm creating a Kubernetes cluster and using MetalLB (https://metallb.universe.tf/) as my load balancer. I've managed to configure everything to work for internal IP addressing but then wanted MetalLB to be able to allocate external IP addresses.

To do this, I've added a new interface to my machines called `ens192`. The interface already on the machine for internal networking is `ens160`.

My plan was that I could configure the interface and routing without an IP, ready to be allocated when required. However, it doesn't seem to like this.

For arguments sake, my IP range is `233.233.233.161/27`. Here is my `ifcfg-ens192`. Keeping in mind this system already has an interface ens160 I haven't configured another gateway -

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="static"
DEFROUTE="no"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPV6INIT="no"
NAME="ens192"
DEVICE="ens192"

NETMASK="255.255.255.224"
BROADCAST="233.233.233.191"

DNS1="8.8.8.8"
DNS2="8.8.4.4"
```

Then I have setup basic routing with `route-ens192` file -

```
default via 233.233.233.161 dev ens192
233.233.233.161/27 via 233.233.233.161 dev ens192
```

However, even if I assign an IP address to this interface I cannot get anything pinging and when running `ifup ens192` I get -

```
[root@m1 network-scripts]# ifup ens192
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
```

I hope someone can help - I'm not the most proficient at routing!

Answer (score 0):

The error message is related to the `link` status of the interface, not to the `IPv4` configuration.

The link status on hardware devices is typically related to the cable connection at both ends although this can also be controlled through software.

See the `man ip` for more details:

https://linux.die.net/man/8/ip

````
ip link set - change device attributes

dev NAME (default)
    NAME specifies network device to operate on. When configuring SR-IOV Virtual Fuction (VF) devices, this keyword should specify the associated Physical Function (PF) device. 
up and down
    change the state of the device to UP or DOWN. ```

In case wires are connected properly, try a command such as `ip link set dev ens192 up`.
````